# SQL Error (245): Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '50%' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

***Definitions***

```
[Rec_Num] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Pro_PCT] [nvarchar](50) NULL
[Max_Off] [nvarchar](50) NULL
[IsExceeds]  AS (CONVERT([int],[Pro_PCT])-CONVERT([int],replace([Max_Off],'%','')))
```

***Data***

[image]

***Query***

```
select top 200 * from dbo.FO_Entry
where isexceeds>0
order by Rec_Num desc
```

The above query works fine and shows the data.  But when I change the top 200 to 201 then it throws the below error.

[image]

If I run the Top 201 statement 2 or three times then it shows the data.  Again if I change the Top 201 to To 202 then again the error popsup.

Any suggestion will be very much helpful.

***Note:-***
Problem occurs when I use where ***IsExceeds>0*** condition.  Also I believe that the IsExceeds calculation may be causing this issue.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. The real problem, however, is why are you storing numerical data as an `nvarchar`? A percentage, for example, is a decimal value: 100% is `1.00`, and 73.27% would be `0.7327`.

Comment: Both [Pro_PCT] and [Max_Off] data is stored as Text.  Could you please guide me how to handle this.  Updated Note in the end of my question.

Comment: If you can't change the data, you'll have to profile the data for non-numeric literals, and their typical format. One we saw is a percent sign in the string. The error message says that , too. So try: `(CONVERT([int],REPLACE([Pro_PCT],'%','')) -CONVERT([int],replace([Max_Off],'%','')))` .

Comment: What data is in that troublesome row 201?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is your design, fix that, and the problem goes away. Your column `Pro_PCT` is clearly an `int`, and your column `Max_off` is clearly meant to be a `decimal`; as it is a percentage.

We'll fix `Pro_Pct` first. Firstly check if any values are "bad" (which I don't doubt there will be because you're storing numerical data as a `nvarchar`):

```sql
SELECT YourIdColumn
       Pro_PCT
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int,Pro_PCT) IS NULL
  AND Pro_PCT IS NOT NULL;
```

That will give you a dataset back of all the bad data. You'll need to fix **all** of those values.

After that, you can `ALTER` the table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN ProPCT int NULL; --Change to NOT NULL as appropriate
```

Now the percentage. First we need to remove all the percent (`'%'`) characters and turn the value into a `decimal`. Again, let's get the bad data:

```sql
SELECT YourIDColumn,
       [Max_Off]
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10,4),REPLACE(Max_Off,N'%',N''))
  AND Max_Off IS NOT NULL;
```

Again, fix all your values where it couldn't be converted. Then you can `UPDATE` the value and then `ALTER` the table:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Max_Off = TRY_CONVERT(decimal(6,4),REPLACE(Max_Off,N'%',N'')) / 100.00
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN Max_Off decimal(6,4) NOT NUll; --Again, change to NULL if needed
```

Now your data is fixed, you should have an easier time implementing the logic for `IsExcess`.